Google Authentication Fails on Real Device but Works on Emulator in .Net Maui
I'm implementing Google authentication in a .Net Maui app using Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth. The authentication works perfectly on the emulator, but fails on real devices. Here’s the relevant code:


public partial class GoogleAuthService
{
    public static Activity _activity;
    public static GoogleSignInOptions _gso;
    public static GoogleSignInClient _googleSignInClient;

    private TaskCompletionSource<GoogleUserDTO> _taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<GoogleUserDTO>();

    private Task<GoogleUserDTO> GoogleAuthentication
    {
        get => _taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    public GoogleAuthService()
    {
        _activity = Platform.CurrentActivity;

        _gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn)
            .RequestIdToken(WebApiKey)
            .RequestEmail()
            .RequestId()
            .RequestProfile()
            .Build();

        _googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.GetClient(_activity, _gso);

        MainActivity.ResultGoogleAuth += MainActivity_ResultGoogleAuth;
    }

    public Task<GoogleUserDTO> AuthenticateAsync()
    {
        _taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<GoogleUserDTO>();

        _activity.StartActivityForResult(_googleSignInClient.SignInIntent, 9001);

        return GoogleAuthentication;
    }

    private void MainActivity_ResultGoogleAuth(object sender, (bool Success, GoogleSignInAccount Account) e)
    {
        if (e.Success)
        {
            try
            {
                var currentAccount = e.Account;

                _taskCompletionSource.SetResult(
                    new GoogleUserDTO
                    {
                        Email = currentAccount.Email,
                        FullName = currentAccount.DisplayName,
                        TokenId = currentAccount.IdToken,
                        UserName = currentAccount.GivenName,
                    });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _taskCompletionSource.SetException(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<GoogleUserDTO> GetCurrentUserAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var user = await _googleSignInClient.SilentSignInAsync();
            return new GoogleUserDTO
            {
                Email = user.Email,
                FullName = $"{user.DisplayName}",
                TokenId = user.IdToken,
                UserName = user.GivenName
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Task LogoutAsync() => _googleSignInClient.SignOutAsync();
}



Problem:
The authentication works on the emulator, but fails on real devices. On real devices, SilentSignInAsync throws exceptions, and manual sign-in via AuthenticateAsync results in failure.
Expected Behavior:
Authentication should work on real devices just like on the emulator.
Error Messages:
SilentSignInAsync fails with exceptions.
Manual sign-in (AuthenticateAsync) does not complete successfully.
Attempts:
Checked permissions for Google Play Services on the real device.
Verified correct WebApiKey and scopes are requested.
Tried debugging on the real device, but no specific error is thrown.
Question:
What steps should I take to resolve Google authentication issues on real devices in Xamarin.Android using Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth?

Can you give a more complete error message？

There is no error message. I don't understand why everything works fine on the emulator, but on the real device after I select the e-mail for authorization nothing happens.

This might not directly answer your question about GooglePlayServices.Auth, but you could try using WebAuthenticator to implement Google Sign-In. I recently shared a GitHub example on this topic: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/.NET-MAUI-Cookbook/tree/main/Chapter05/c5-GoogleAuth
